# How to handle a Wordpress blog with articles in different languages?

Tags: plugins, themes, multi-language, customization, language

Most multilanguage plugins have the approach to provide each post in different languages. In that case, qTranslate or WPML are good plugins. But in my case, articles have one language and instead of translating them, there should be versions of the blog showing only the content in one language.

For example the `en.example.com` should only show posts written in English language, and also display Theme texts in English, while `de.example.com` should only show German articles and also use German as system language for Wordpress. (URLs could also have the language code in slashes instead of using a subdomain, like `www.example.com/en/`.)

Is there a good solution for this use case? I could think of using a plugin or integrating the concept into the theme. Or is the best solution to set up one Wordpress installation for each language?

Comment: Both plugins you mentioned can do this. You have to just configure them to don't show posts that are not in current language. Probably you need to modify your theme for that. However, if you want to keep thing better organized a network install is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you are better with using two different installations or two different sites on a network installation. The only use case for the plugins is when you need almost all of your content to be translated or when you need good control over what was translated and what wasn't.

Comment: what about the links coming to your site? are the handled by wordpress.
let's assume you have example.com/post_1 as an article what happens if you move the site to multisite?
will it still be visible under example.com/post_1, is it only visible under en.example.com/post_1 and gives an 404 on the other link? As I am working with danijar we try to avoid 404s on the new installation.

Comment: this seems to be a new question, please ask it properly if you don't find enough documentation or it doesn't work for you. In brief the answer is that there is no reason to have a problem with that.